# R: add labels to .dta files using `haven`

Tags: r, label, stata

I am using both Stata and R in my project and I would like to label variables in R so that Stata reads them correctly.

Take the following database with 12 variables correctly labelled in Stata

```
* these are Stata commands
sysuse auto
save sysuseauto.dta
```

I can import the data into R

```
# import
library(haven)
library(data.table)
auto<-read_dta("sysuseauto.dta")
```

Do note that R maintains all variable labels as specified in Stata.
I would like to create a new variable in R

```
# Creating a new variable
sapply(auto,class)
auto<-setDT(auto)[,n_cars_by_foreign:=.N,by=.(foreign)]
```

and label it so that when I open the new data in Stata, it is correctly labelled.

However, I am unable to label the variable so that Stata reads it.
I have tried the following

```
attr(auto, "haven_labelled") <- c(n_cars_by_foreign = "Number of cars by foreign")
write_dta(auto, "sysuseauto2.dta")
# and 
attr(auto, "var.labels") <- c(n_cars_by_foreign = "Number of cars by foreign")
write_dta(auto, "sysuseauto3.dta")
```

However, not only the label does not appear the variable name using `View(data)`, but also when I import back `sysuseauto2.dta` and `sysuseauto3.dta` into Stata the new variable is not labelled correctly.

Does anyone know how to approach this issue?

thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: Which Stata version are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. The code below works on Stata 16.1 and `R 4.0.3` with `data.table_1.13.4` and `haven_2.3.1`.

The only difference is the way you were assigning the label to the variable. Instead of
`attr(auto, "haven_labelled") <- c(n_cars_by_foreign = "You New Label")` it should be `attr(auto$n_cars_by_foreign, "label") <- "You New Label"`

```
library(haven)
library(data.table)
# Get data from Stata (16.1)
auto<-read_dta("sysuseauto.dta")
# Gerenating new variable
auto <- setDT(auto)[,n_cars_by_foreign:=.N,by=.(foreign)]
# Extract the value label of "n_cars_by_foreign" (which is NULL)
attr(auto$n_cars_by_foreign, "label")
## NULL

# Adding the label value
attr(auto$n_cars_by_foreign, "label") <- "Number of cars by foreign"
#Check that value label variable is in place 
attr(auto$n_cars_by_foreign, "label")
## [1] "Number of cars by foreign"

## Save the data
write_dta(auto, "sysuseauto2.dta")
```

Comment: Hello @ÁlvaroA.Gutiérrez-Vargas, I was wondering do you have any suggestions on how to do this for multiple variables at once.

Comment: @Alex, probably I will generate a small function and plug it into a `lapply` that calls another list with the labels. However, I think it is long enough to create another question.